# amazon ec2 service(linux) cannot use tomcat7 or 6

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

i just use `yum install tomcat7` to setup the tomcat7 and change the port, in the /usr/share/tomcat/conf/server.xml from 8080 to 80 and `service tomcat6 start`, it works fine.
but when i do the netstat -nlp, there is no 80 port, and also other cannot visit the 80 port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to create ROOT, i think you did not create it yet, that way make your website unavaialbel.

Answer (score 1):

When you do netstat it typically will show you `http`, not 80: this is because 80 is bound to http in /etc/services. You'll see something like this:

```
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN
```

Assuming you're not experiencing a Tomcat error, make sure that you've set up the EC2 security group to allow access to port 80. Look at [this](http://scottpatten.ca/2011/11/opening-up-ec2-ports-internally.html) for a decent treatment.

EDIT: if 8080 works but 80 doesn't then it is either:

1. Some other program (such as Apache) sitting on port 80.
2. You're probably not running with the right privileges. On most Linux distributions you need to be the root user (or running as a system process) to access ports numbered less than 1023

Comment: and i think it is something relative to my configration, it is ok if i use 8080, but changing to 80 make it cannot work anymore(change the server.xml)

Comment: i think so, but which directory need to be chmod? actually i am exactly root